# Removing the words from the sentences

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing text, I am trying to remove certain words from the text that are stored in a vector. Please help me achieve this!

```
stopwords <- c("today","hot","outside","so","its")
df <- data.frame(a = c("a1", "a2", "a3"), text = c("today the weather looks hot", "its so rainy outside", "today its sunny"))
```

Expected Output:

```
   a                        text          new_text
1 a1 Today the weather looks hot the weather looks
2 a2        its so rainy outside             rainy
3 a3             today its sunny             sunny
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paste all the `stopwords` together and use `gsub` to remove them.

```
df$new_text <- trimws(gsub(paste0(stopwords, collapse = "|"), "", df$text))
df
#   a                        text          new_text
#1 a1 today the weather looks hot the weather looks
#2 a2        its so rainy outside             rainy
#3 a3             today its sunny             sunny
```

Or with `str_remove_all`

```
stringr::str_remove_all(df$text, paste0(stopwords, collapse = "|"))
```

Just to be extra-safe add word boundaries around each `stopwords` so that, `"so"` from `"something"` or `"some"` is not replaced.

```
df$new_text <- trimws(gsub(paste0("\\b", stopwords, "\\b",
               collapse = "|"), "", df$text))
```

Comment: there is an question by me on how to keep the certain words ! Could i make changes to the code above to achieve this. PLease help with your answer!, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58302626/keeping-certain-words-in-the-sentences

Comment: @prog Looks like you deleted ?

Comment: i have undeleted it now, pls check