# Keeping certain words in the sentences

Tags: r

I have a dataframe containing text, I am trying to keep only certain words from the text that are stored in a vector and remove the ones not in the vector. Please help me achieve this!

```
stopwords <- c("the","weather","looks","rainy","sunny")
df <- data.frame(a = c("a1", "a2", "a3"), text = c("today the weather looks hot", "its so rainy outside", "today its sunny"))
```

Expected Output:

```
   a                        text          new_text
1 a1 Today the weather looks hot the weather looks
2 a2        its so rainy outside             rainy
3 a3             today its sunny             sunny
```

Code I tried:

```
df$new_text <- trimws(gsub(paste0("\\b", stopwords, "\\b",
               collapse = "|"), stopwords, df$text))
```

Code leads to wrong repitions,Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a direct regex to do this however, we can also split words and find the common ones

```
sapply(strsplit(df$text, "\\s+"), function(x) 
      paste0(intersect(x, stopwords), collapse = " "))

#[1] "the weather looks" "rainy"             "sunny"
```

**data**

```
df <- data.frame(a = c("a1", "a2", "a3"), text = c("today the weather looks hot", 
     "its so rainy outside", "today its sunny"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```